# Default Value in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have one table
'table_a'

| date | status |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-04-25 | 1 |
| 2021-04-25 | 0 |
| 2021-04-25 | 1 |
| 2021-04-27 | 1 |
| 2021-04-27 | 1 |
| 2021-04-27 | 1 |
| 2021-04-29 | 0 |
| 2021-04-29 | 0 |

Condition

1. COUNT when `status` = 1
2. When date is empty in 'table_a', default count is 0
3. where date 2021-04-25 until 2021-04-28

I want to make like this

| 2021-04-25 | 2021-04-26 | 2021-04-27 | 2021-04-28 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 0 | 3 | 0 |

Thanks bro

Answer (score 0):

I guess I can figure out a query for this. But *dates* will be rows, not columns.
The most tricky thing is to generate missed (in table_a) dates in the result set. But we can do it this way:

```
select T.date2, coalesce(sum(table_a.`status`),0) from table_a right join
    (select adddate('2021-04-25', @d := @d + 1) as date2 from (select @d := -1) as T 
          join Large_Table where @d < 5) as T on T.date2 = table_a.date1
where table_a.date1 between '2021-04-25' and '2021-04-28'
group by 1;
```

Important notice: you need to use any additional table in your databse (*Large_Table* in the query above) to join on. It can be any table (data is not important) but it must contain at least 4 records in this case. This trick is needed to generate dates.